# Using mongoose custom connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unsure of where to define a mongoose custom connection. I currently have it set up in my server.js file, but when looking at the documentation, it seems like it is defined inside the model file itself, since they are using the connection object after to create the connection to the model.

//From DOC's

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var Tank = connection.model('Tank', yourSchema);
```

The Problem I have is since I have the connection made in server file, it does not know what `connection` is.

//Server.js

```
var databaseUri = "mongodb://localhost/food";

if (process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
    mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
    mongoose.createConnection(databaseUri)
}

var database = mongoose.connection;

database.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", err);
});

database.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});
```

My model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "First Name is Required"
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Last Name is Required"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Email is Required"
  }
});

//I need to use the connection I made in server js here, but not sure how. I tried exporting it from server file but it is not working.
var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your **server.js**, you'll need to require the `User` which will be:

```
//connecton to the location of the database you use
let databaseUri = "mongodb://localhost/food"; //you didn't include your port number. I try it on "mongodb://localhost:3000/food"
let user = require('User'); //NOTE: ensure you reference the location of the `User` file correctly

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let ip = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';

console.log("server started at http//:" + ip + ":" + port);
```

This should be in your Model:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

//variable that will hold my connection
let database = mongoose.connection;
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    // User Schema
    let UserSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
            type: String
        },var UserSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "First Name is Required"
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Last Name is Required"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Email is Required"
  }
});


//This line below exports the whole module to mongoose.model
module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Ahh I see, and then establish the connection there.

Comment: When you say connection, do you mean like the `localhost:27017/test` thing?

Comment: No I mean do what they have in their doc's but have it in my server file instead. After importing User, I was thinking of doing something like `User = connection.model('User', yourSchema);` but in server file

Comment: I dont think this will work actually since I have this in my model instead and export it there, I dont think it would make sense to have this in my server and export it from there, unless that is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to use the createConnection() from mongoose and not the regular connection(). Also, isn't creating a connection in the model itself not a great place to do it?